# Passing variable data to component controller Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let career of careers">
    <label>{{career.name}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" attr.id="{{career.id}}" (change)="doSomethingWithId($event.target)"
</div>
```

The TS Component:

```
doSomethingWithId(target: Element): void {
     console.log(target.attributes.id);
}
```

The id here gives an error:

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'NamedNodeMap'.

I don't know if attr.id is the best way even or if it should just be id, or even data-id. But I need to get the career.id of what was clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding for your `id` is wrong.
Change this

```
 attr.id="{{career.id}}"
```

to this

```
[attr.id]="career.id"
```

**Update 1**
If you just want the career id, you can just pass it directly in your function like this

```
<input type="checkbox (change)="doSomethingWithId(career.id)"
```

and in your service

```
doSomethingWithId(target): void {
     console.log(target);
}
```

Comment: I think you can do it either way can't you?  Either way, I changed it but the same error exists. Is attr.id the best way to do this or should I be using like data-id?

Comment: If he wanted to use interpolation, he can just leave off the 'attr' part.

id="{{ career.id }}"

Comment: @Samir why not just pass the career id in your function? you don't need to set the id in your input to get it. If that's what you want I can update my answer

Comment: Note that you don't have to access the 'attributes' property of the DOM element to access ID. You can access it directly from target or srcElement. 

$event.target.id   or $event.srcElement.id

Comment: @Samir glad to help

Comment: @diopside I think the OP is not aware he can just pass the variable to the function. Setting the id and get it from there is possible but might take a lot of setup. Let Angular do the hard work for you.

Comment: its true. that's def the smarter way to do it if you're using discrete mouse listeners for each item. When I have ngFor loops, I usually try to put a single mouse event listener on the parent element, and then delegate click actions based on the srcElement.id attribute of the click $event.  I'm not really sure if it actually benefits performance that much, bc in one case you're adding a bunch of mouse listeners, and in the other case you're adding a bunch of attribute bindings. Angular can't really do "one time" binding so those bindings stay active even though their value doesn't change.

Comment: @diopside I think going the attribute bindings route would be better because it is easier to maintain and read. I may not understand Angular in a deeper level, but I think the performance impact is negligible.